# Cassandra - Out of memory (large server)

Tags: linux, cassandra, nosql

About cassandra, we started using a cluster with a very high workload (4 hosts) The machines have 128Gb each and 64 CPU. My max_heap is with 48 GB and my new_heap is with 2 GB. What is considered in this case? Anyone?
There is no script or anything that analyzes this type of configuration.

The older servers running 60Gb and 16 procs, and thats ok.

Why this problem?

Comment: Are you getting a specific error?  I can tell you, that if you're using CMS GC, that a 2GB heap is **WAY** too small.  TBH, I would start with a 32GB Heap (Xmx and Xms) and a heap new size (Xmn) of 13GB to 16GB.

Comment: better start with 31g, but then use G1GC...

Comment: I just did the standard installation, and changed the items below only.

MAX_HEAP_SIZE = "48G"
HEAP_NEWSIZE = "2G"

About Xmx changes, Xms. Wouldn't it be just these 2 items that I changed? This is the second time that I just change the cassandra.

Comment: Regarding the CMC GC or G1GC, how do I check this item? As I said, I'm starting now and I already have this problem.

By the way, when I generated the error, I was applying a repair.

Here is a piece of the error.

Comment: ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000055f23b126f00):  JavaThread "MessagingService-Incoming-/10.XX.XX.XX" [_thread_new, id=443614, stack(0x00007f94479c9000,0x00007f9447a0a000)]

Stack: [0x00007f94479c9000,0x00007f9447a0a000],  sp=0x00007f9447a08b40,  free space=254k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0xadf8ed]  VMError::report_and_die()+0x15d
V  [libjvm.so+0x4f4c6a]  report_vm_out_of_memory(char const*, int, unsigned long,

Comment: VMErrorType, char const*)+0xaa
V  [libjvm.so+0x8c2ec0]  os::pd_commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, bool)+0xc0
V  [libjvm.so+0x8ba43e]  os::commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, bool)+0x2e
V  [libjvm.so+0x8c4457]  os::pd_create_stack_guard_pages(char*, unsigned long)+0x77
V  [libjvm.so+0xa85296]  JavaThread::create_stack_guard_pages()+0x66
V  [libjvm.so+0xa8946c]  JavaThread::run()+0x3c
V  [libjvm.so+0x8c0402]  java_start(Thread*)+0xf2
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x7dd5]  start_thread+0xc5

Comment: I saw...I am using G1GC

Comment: [11:08:33] root@cassandra01-btg:/etc/dse/cassandra$ cat jvm.options  | grep -v "^#"  | grep -v ^$
-ea
-XX:+UseThreadPriorities
-XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Xss256k
-XX:StringTableSize=1000003
-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
-XX:-UseBiasedLocking
-XX:+UseTLAB
-XX:+ResizeTLAB
-XX:+UseNUMA
-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500